What happens to a standing acoustic wave, when the length of the tube, closed at both ends, isn't an integer of half the wavelength?
Suppose you have a tube with two rigid boundaries at each end. The tube is filled with water at about 25°C. One end is equipped with a transducer that produces a wave with a frequency of $f=36$ kHz. The tube has a total length of $L= 9.6$ cm. The wavelength of the wave is $\lambda\approx 4.1$ cm. In simple harmonics in tubes, where there is no forced frequency, the following condition is met
$L = \frac{n\lambda}{2}, \quad \text{where } n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.
In this case, I suppose, the frequency adjusts so nodes and antinodes can be in their places.
However, since the frequency is forced and the length is also not variable and the boundary conditions dictate that a displacement node at each end has to form (rigid boundary), how will the standing acoustic wave look? Since there is a mismatch between the length of the tube and the wavelength, are the pressure nodes and antiniodes stable in  place? What happens to the extra space?
I can't find anything in normal books about acoustics about standing waves under these conditions, when there is a mismatch. All books only talk about the ideal standing wave, where everything aligns. Can anyone suggest anything?

Standing waves are eigenmodes of the system for specific boundary conditions.E.g., we have wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2}=0,\\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0
$$
(Note that these are not the only possible boundary conditions leading to standing waves - choose whateever is approrpriate to yoru problem.)
We can find the explicit form of the eigenmodes, using Fourier transform or separation of variables or another method for solving second order partial differential equations (there are many texts on this subject, so I leave it as an exercise.) The solutions have form of standing waves:
$$
u_n(x,t)=\sin(k_nx)\cos(\omega_nt+\phi), \\k_n=\frac{\pi}{L}n, \omega_n=vk_n, n=1, 2,3,...
$$
Any other solution of this equation can be represented as an eigenmode expansion (again, extensively covered in textbooks):
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_nc_nu_n(x,t)
$$
Note that this solution must satisfy the same boundary conditions. E.g., for the boundary conditions used above, if we take the initial state of the field as $u(x,0)=v_0(x)$, where $v_0(0)\neq0$ and/or $v_0(L)\neq0$, this would be a mathematical nonsense. Physically it means that a part of this solution would quickly decay, and the remaining part, $\tilde{v}_0(x)$ would satisfy boundary conditions. We can then find the solution by calculating the coefficients in the eigenmode expansion above from the initial condition:
$$
u(x,0)=\sum_nc_nu_n(x,0)=\sum_nc_n\sin(k_nx)=\tilde{v}_0(x)
$$
(by simply matching coefficients or using Fourier transform/Hilbert space apparatus.)
Remark
The actual question deals with a tube that is continuously forced, that is the equation to be solved or the boundary conditions are different. E.g., something like:
$$
u(0,t)=0, u(L,t)=w_0\cos(\Omega t)
$$

Thank you for the answer. I made an attempt to solve the wave equation with the specific boundary conditions, as you had suggested in your remark, but I am neither a physicist nor mathematician, so I arrived at my university math limits. I realized I also have to account for a phase shift upon reflection, which isnt an integer of pi/4, given the tube length, however assumin 100% reflection at the boundary. Now my solution has A cos (kx-kL) e^( i \omega t) \cos(kL) . Does that sound plausible to you? Thanks

@BubbleFlow it is possible, but I can't say more without knowing boundary conditions. I suggest asking this as a new specific question (but try to make it more than just solving equations - otherwise it might be closed as a holework.)

@BubbleFlow or you could include more precise formulation as an edit/update to your question.
